# Unable to receive pushNotifications from Firebase connected through application server

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a new project in firebase console for apple APNs pushNotifications. I followed all the instructions in firebase documentation like generating SSl certificate and uploading p12 certificates(development and production) to firebase and also the provisioning profile. And also added the whole required code in Appdelegate. And also activated pushNotifications in capabilities and also in Entitlement file APNs enviroment set as development.

When I'm sending a sample message from firebase notification messageing, my iPhone(6) able to receive the notification(send through both FCM token and also with bundelId able to receive notification). But from my application server with same FCM token I'm unable to receive notifications, but my server side getting reply as notification sent Ok with 200 code from firebase.

I am unable to get the solution from last week and also not getting where is issue from mobile side or from server side.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: You config completed.?

Comment: I am getting in my console log as   <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my problem.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
} else {
    // iOS 8 or later
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]
}

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

[FIRApp configure];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
return YES;
}
```

in my above code I not written

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
```

this line,actually which is not in firebase direct documentation.

And also check whether may get notifications which will print in console by using this method

```
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
// Print full message
NSLog(@"Notification :%@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
```

But notification may not be appear on notifications screen,because the apns formate is

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testing.. (0)","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

but from server side it may be a different format.